# Jenkins convert 'pipeline script from SCM' to 'Freestyle project'

Tags: jenkins, email-notifications

Currently we have a project that contains a 'pipeline script from SCM', but we would like to add an editable email notification for the results of these builds. To do this, we need to create a 'Freestyle project'. I can not find the option 'pipeline script from SCM' in a Freestyle project and I have no knowledge of Jenkins whatsoever. I have tried clicking on everything that contains "Git" and "pipeline", but I did not get any further.
Does anyone have an idea how I can easily convert this pipeline script from SCM within a Freestyle project?

I currently start the build of this project within the Freestyle project, but then I can not refer to the html results of the other project.

Comment: You juat add the [configuration to your pipeline](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/#pipeline-step) from SCM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can I add this to the pipeline from SCM? The only options available is to change the repository URL of GitLab, credentials, branch specifier, repository browser and script path.

Comment: You go to your SCM source, find your pipeline file (ie:jenkinsfile, edit and save. You should have a sctipt generator option  if you create a new pipleine job, there should be a "pipeline syntax" generator that can help you get it right and paste that into the jenkinsfile.